# NullPointerException On write to file to Create JAR

Tags: java, file, jar, nullpointerexception

I am trying to write to a file to create a JAR.
But I am having problem with `NullPointerException`. My files are in Classpath.

(I use `getClass()` because I will be creating a JAR file. )

Any reason I would get a `NullPointerException` here? Thanks for your help.

Here is the code:

```
package Library;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class WriteJARSample {
public WriteJARSample() throws URISyntaxException, FileNotFoundException,    FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    write();
}
public void write() throws URISyntaxException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    try{
        File Mf=new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("AllBookRecords.txt").toURI());
        File Tf=new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Boutput.txt").toURI());
        BufferedReader Bbr=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("AllBookRecords.txt")));
        PrintWriter Bpw=new PrintWriter(Mf);
        String Bs;
        while( (Bs=Bbr.readLine()) != null ){
                Bpw.println(Bs);
        }
        Bpw.close();
        Bbr.close();
        Mf.delete();
        Tf.renameTo(Mf);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){

    }
    catch(URISyntaxException urise){

    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    new WriteJARSample();
}
}
```

Comment: In which line is the NullPointerException thrown?

Comment: Check if `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Boutput.txt"` returns `null`.

Comment: remove the classloader and only use `getClass().getResource()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getClass().getResourceAsStream("AllBookRecords.txt")` differs for the prior access of "AllBookRecords.txt", maybe it should also be:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("AllBookRecords.txt")
```

or simply

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/AllBookRecords.txt")
```

`getClass().getResource(AsStream)` works relative to the class package (subdirectory).